# Oracle SQL - Not Exists - string does not exist in a list of values

Tags: sql, string, oracle, not-exists

Background:  For a SPRIDEN_id, sprhold_hldd_code may have one or more of several values or NO values.

I need to select SP.SPRIDEN_ID,  SP.SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME,  SP.SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME,  SR.SHRDGMR_SEQ_NO,   SR.SHRDGMR_PROGRAM

Where (sh.sprhold_hldd_code = 'RH') does not exist.

So far, no records are returned.

I have found that if I put a code that is not in the list of possible values (such as Z) in sh.sprhold_hldd_code = 'Z', then it will return results.

```
DATA: (column names abbreviated)
SPRIDEN_ID   SPRIDEN_LAST   SPRIDEN_FIRST  SHRDGMR_SEQ_NO   SHRDGMR_PROGRAM sh.sprhold_hldd_code
100001       Smith          Sue            1                ALHE            RH
100001       Smith          Sue            1                ALHE            AA
100001       Smith          Sue            1                ALHE            BB
100005       Conners        Tim            1                BUSN            RH
100008       Occent         Mary           1                MATH            CC
100008       Occent         Mary           1                MATH            AA

Expected Results: Mary is the only record that does NOT have the RH code.

SPRIDEN_ID   SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME   SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME  SHRDGMR_SEQ_NO  SHRDGMR_PROGRAM
100008       Occent              Mary                1                MATH
```

I receive no results though.

```
CODE:
Select SP.SPRIDEN_ID, SP.SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME, SP.SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME, SR.SHRDGMR_SEQ_NO,          SR.SHRDGMR_PROGRAM
from spriden SP
join SHRDGMR SR on SP.SPRIDEN_PIDM = SR.SHRDGMR_PIDM
join SPRHOLD SH on sp.spriden_pidm = sh.sprhold_pidm
where SR.SHRDGMR_DEGS_CODE = 'PN'
  and SR.SHRDGMR_TERM_CODE_GRAD >= '201489'
  and sp.spriden_change_ind is NULL
and not exists
(select sh.sprhold_pidm
from sprhold sh
where sh.sprhold_hldd_code = 'RH')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the data you want, I would recommend using aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
Select SP.SPRIDEN_ID, SP.SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME, SP.SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME, SR.SHRDGMR_SEQ_NO, 
       SR.SHRDGMR_PROGRAM
from spriden SP join
     SHRDGMR SR
     on SP.SPRIDEN_PIDM = SR.SHRDGMR_PIDM join
     SPRHOLD SH
     on sp.spriden_pidm = sh.sprhold_pidm
where SR.SHRDGMR_DEGS_CODE = 'PN' and
      SR.SHRDGMR_TERM_CODE_GRAD >= '201489' and
     sp.spriden_change_ind is NULL
group by SP.SPRIDEN_ID, SP.SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME, SP.SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME, SR.SHRDGMR_SEQ_NO, 
         SR.SHRDGMR_PROGRAM
having sum(case when sh.sprhold_hldd_code = 'RH' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

You have two problems with your approach.  The first is that the subquery either returns true or false and affects all rows in the original query.  You really want a correlated subquery.  But, even if you got that right, you would be returning duplicate rows for Mary.  This solves both those problems.

Comment: Yes!  That is what I was looking for.  I knew there was something similar to NVL2(expression1, expr2, expr3) but not fore nulls!  Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can do small change and try

```
and sh.sprhold_pidm not in
(select sh.sprhold_pidm
from sprhold sh
where sh.sprhold_hldd_code = 'RH')
```

Comment: Your answer worked for the same problem I had in a different script that was more intensive.    Thank you!!